# Windows XPe - no shutdown.exe / "Access is denied"

Tags: windows, windows-xp, shutdown, windows-xp-embedded

this is my first time posting and asking for help as I really can't get my head round it.

I'm an IT Technician in a team of 3 (including me) that work in a college. We had an old digital signage system that ran on 6 Samsung screens using MagicInfo. If you've ever had the unfortunate job of having to work with this program, then you'll understand my pain...

Our version of MagicInfo is very outdated and is no longer supported. As you can see from my last paragraph, my thoughts on the program aren't exactly that it's the pinnacle of human creation, and so I decided to forget about purchasing an update and figure a way round.

The screens run on Windows XP embedded. I've mapped a shared folder to them all and placed a presentation in there simply labelled: 'Presentation', and have told them to run that upon startup. This works brilliantly as the presentations change every week and the only thing that *Mr. User* has to do is replace the presentation in that folder with the updated version (under the same name). When I then reboot the screen, they play the newly updated file.

Instead of having *Mr. User* walk round and manually turn them on/off, I decided to write a .BAT file that would reboot it for them (yes, we can VNC into them and reboot, but *Mr. User* isn't exactly the most IT literate person on Earth...).

My .BAT file looked like:

```
shutdown /r /m \\(SCREEN IP)
```

This is all well and good, but the only issue is that XPe doesn't seem to come with SHUTDOWN.EXE. I've tried a multitude of programs claiming that they can be used to remotely shutdown, but to no avail.

I've just recently tried taking SHUTDOWN.EXE from my local machine and placing it into System32. When I locally try to run the shutdown command in CMD, I get:`Access is Denied`, which is a step forward as it is at least referencing the executable as opposed to just telling me

```
shutdown is not a recognised....blah blah blah...
```

**TL;DR** **(Too long, didn't read) :**

> Windows XP embedded
>
> No SHUTDOWN.EXE
>
> When SHUTDOWN.EXE is placed into System32 and trying 'shutdown' command in CMD, get response: `Access is denied`

*Additional Information:*
The screens have EWF on them and I do have to 'commit' changes when they are made.

Comment: As an added note re: 'Access is denied' - I'm logged on as the system admin. I have also tried creating another user with admin privileges and trying that, but still no cigar.

Comment: Are you on a Windows domain or is this a standalone computer?

Comment: Yup, both the screens and I are hooked up to the same domain.

Comment: Do you use group policy on your domain?  It sounds to me like you might be getting blocked from running shutdown.exe via group policy.  Are you a domain administrator?

Comment: Actually, you had mentioned that you are running this on Windows xp embedded.  Do you mean you are doing this from a thin client of some sort?   Do you have write access to the storage device on the embedded machine?  Most thin clients do not allow you to write stuff to the hard disk.  One option would be to put shutdown.exe on a network share, and in your batch file do a pushd command to pop that network directory into memory, and run shutdown from the network share.  I can give you some examples if you need.

Comment: Also if you can give the full error text above where you say shutdown is not a recognised....blah blah blah... It would be helpful for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: And shutdown.exe is included in Windows XP. Not too sure if it is included in XP embedded, but you still could be blocked from running it via group policy.

Comment: Try running gpresult /V and post the output in your answer.  The uppercase V is important

Comment: Hi Richie - No, I don't have a group policy on the domain that disables the use of shutdown.exe. I am a domain administrator.
No, the screens are not thin clients - they come with XPe installed as the OS, and yes, I do have Write access on the machine. 
As for the `shutdown is not a recognised command` thing, that was before I had copied shutdown.exe into System32. It was just telling me that it didn't exist. Now that it is on there, I just get `Access is denied`.

Comment: Another option would be to copy shutdown somewhere else on the system other than system32 and try to run it directly from that directory to see if you get access is denied from another directory.   If you can run it from another directory, add the path to the shutdown.exe to the $PATH variable and then you should be able to execute the file from anywhere within the file system, which will make scripting a bit easier.  That or do the pushd thing I mentioned above, let me know if you need help with that

Comment: Hi Richie, after playing around with it all day today, we've found a way to get 'psexec' to work and have successfully got that up and running. Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: Don't forget to post your own answer, so others may benefit :)